# Adding a mouse listener to a rectangle in java

Tags: java, swing, listener, mouselistener

As the title suggests, I am attempting to add an action listener to a basic shape on a window.  I'm wondering if this is even possible?  I'm getting errors when I attempt to add the listener.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new Main();
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
}

Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(60, 70, 120, 80);

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g1.draw(rect);
    g1.setPaint(Color.yellow);
    g1.fill(rect);
}

Handlerclass handle = new Handlerclass();
rect.addMouseListener(handle);

public class Handlerclass implements MouseListener{
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e){
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't draw directly in your JFrame within its paint method. Instead draw in a JPanel that is held by the JFrame's contentPane or that is the JFrame's contentPane and do the drawing in its paintComponent method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add a mouse listener to that object. If you are trying to detect mouse clicks within it then you want to add a mouse listener to whatever Swing container you are drawing the shape in, then use one of the `contains...` or `intersects...` methods.

Check out the documentation for [Rectangle2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) when you get a chance.