# Mouse Listener on graphics rectangles java

Tags: java, swing

i want to add mouse listeners to the rectangles so that when the user clicks one rectangle and drags the mouse to the next rectangle a line is drawn tracking the users movement and also the current rectangle the user is at must be change color. am new in java therefore your help will be highly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SundayPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

 private Rectangle rec;
 private JPanel p = new JPanel();
 private Graphics graphic;
 public SundayPanel()
 {
  setSize(1000, 150);
  setBackground(Color.white);
  setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.orange, Color.red));

  rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 130, 100);
 }

 public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
  Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 72);

     g.setFont(font);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  //g.draw(rec);
  g.draw3DRect(0, 0, 130, 100, true);
  g.drawString("1", 50, 65);
  g.draw3DRect(130, 0, 130, 100, true);
  g.drawString("2", 180, 65);
  g.draw3DRect(260, 0, 130, 100, true);
  g.drawString("3", 300, 65);
  g.draw3DRect(390, 0, 130, 100, true);
  g.drawString("4", 430, 65);
  g.draw3DRect(520, 0, 130, 100, true);
  g.drawString("5", 550, 65);
  g.draw3DRect(650, 0, 130, 100, true);
  g.drawString("6", 700, 65);
  g.draw3DRect(780, 0, 130, 100, true);
  g.drawString("7", 820, 65);
  g.draw3DRect(910, 0, 130, 100, true);
  g.drawString("8", 950, 65);
  g.draw3DRect(1040, 0, 130, 100, true);
  g.drawString("9", 1080, 65);
  g.draw3DRect(1170, 0, 130, 100, true);
  g.drawString("10", 1200, 65);
 }
}

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SundayMain extends JFrame{

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame sunFrame = new SundayFrame("Sunday Today");
  sunFrame.setVisible(true);
  sunFrame.setSize(1330, 150);
  sunFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 }

}


import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SundayFrame extends JFrame{

 private SundayPanel sunPanel;

 public SundayFrame(String title)
 {
  super(title);
  sunPanel = new SundayPanel();
  add(sunPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

 }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a mouse listener to a rectangle in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296438/adding-a-mouse-listener-to-a-rectangle-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your example to draw lines (press button, move mouse, release button).
Code is compileable comparable and can be executed in one `SundayPanel.java` file.
Possible it will help you to achieve your exact goal:

NOTE: be careful - code is pretty ugly.

```
public class SundayPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

    public SundayPanel() {
        setSize(1000, 150);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.orange, Color.red));
    }

    String[] values = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 72);
        g.setFont(font);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int step = 130 * i;
            if ((start != null) && ((int) (end.getX() / 130) == i)) {
                g.setColor(Color.orange);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.gray);
            }
            g.fill3DRect(step, 0, 130, 100, true);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString(values[i], 50 + step, 65);
        }
        if ((start != null) && (end != null)) {
            g.drawLine((int) start.getX(), (int) start.getY(), (int) end.getX(), (int) end.getY());
        }
    }

    Point start;

    Point end;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        start = e.getPoint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        end = e.getPoint();
        e.getComponent().repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        int from = (int) (start.getX() / 130);
        int to = (int) (end.getX() / 130);
        String tmp = values[from];
        values[from] = values[to];
        values[to] = tmp;
        start = end = null;
        e.getComponent().repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}

class SundayMain extends JFrame {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame sunFrame = new SundayFrame("Sunday Today");
        sunFrame.setVisible(true);
        sunFrame.setSize(1330, 150);
        sunFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}

class SundayFrame extends JFrame {

    private SundayPanel sunPanel;

    public SundayFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
        sunPanel = new SundayPanel();
        sunPanel.addMouseListener(sunPanel);
        sunPanel.addMouseMotionListener(sunPanel);
        add(sunPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

}
```

Comment: do i add the mouse actionlistener on the frame itself?

Comment: Adjusted example to apply "like drag-and-drop" behavior.

Comment: @fan you can move exact implementation of listener in separate classes or use "Command" patter to decouple logic.

Comment: @fan looks like I completely applied your requirements (check the code in answer)

Comment: Just added highlighting (missed this requirements)

Comment: am grateful for your help but can i trouble you even more, spent the whole night trying to insure that on mouse release the line drawn is erased.

Comment: Adjusted code with 1 line change (added 'start = end = null' in mouseReleased() method).