# How can I switch between jpanels?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I'm still very new to java programming, so please help me to correct any mistakes I might have overlooked or give tips on how to improve this program.

Okay, so a lot of problems have been solved, and now I have a CardLayout, but I still have questions about how I should make my pipes show inside it.

When I tried to add in my refresh rate timer and my speed timer, I have problems about how I need to declare and initialize boolean variables.

Also, when I compile and run this game, I get files such as `Game$1.class`. Is there a way for me to clean this up, and could someone explain why this happens?  Do these have an affect on the finished product? (When the game is compiled and packaged into a JAR.)

I want to set playerIsReady to true when the play button is clicked. And from there, when the if statement is true, then switch to a panel that displays the pipes, and start moving the pipe across the screen. Preferably 3 instances of that pipe, each starting at different times, but whatever you can help with is fine.

Some of this code needs work, so I have commented some parts out and left notes.

My other questions about this game can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587972/how-can-i-scroll-more-than-one-object-at-the-same-time).

This is my **current** code

Game.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {             
                // the GUI as seen by the user (without frame)
                final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
                final JPanel gui = new JPanel(cl);
                // remove if no border is needed
                gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

                JPanel menu = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                JButton playGame = new JButton("Play!");
                ActionListener playGameListener = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        cl.show(gui, "game");
                    }
                };
                playGame.addActionListener(playGameListener);
                Insets margin = new Insets(20, 50, 20, 50);
                playGame.setMargin(margin);
                menu.add(playGame);
                gui.add(menu);
                cl.addLayoutComponent(menu, "menu");

                final JPanel pipes = new Pipes();
                gui.add(pipes);
                cl.addLayoutComponent(pipes, "game");

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Pipes Game");
                f.add(gui);
                // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
                // all non-daemon threads are finished
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
                // in order display the components within it
                f.pack();
                // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
                // resizing artifacts.
                f.setVisible(true);

                /*if (playerIsReady) { 
                    Timer speed = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {  //pipe speed
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            pipes.move();
                        }
                    });
                    speed.start();

                    Timer refresh = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {    //refresh rate
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            pipes.repaint();
                        }
                    });
                    refresh.start();
                }*/
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Pipes.java

```
// What import(s) do I need for ArrayList?
public class Pipes {
    List<Pipe> pipes = new ArrayList<Pipe>();

    public Pipes() {
        pipes.add(new Pipe(50, 100));
        pipes.add(new Pipe(150, 100));
        pipes.add(new Pipe(250, 100));
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for ( Pipe pipe : pipes ){
            pipe.drawPipe(g);
        }
    }
}
```

PipeObject.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class PipeObject {
    //Declare and initialiaze variables
    int x1 = 754;               //xVal start
    int x2 = 75;                //pipe width
                                //total width is 83
    int y1 = -1;                //yVal start
    int y2 = setHeightVal();    //pipe height
    int gap = 130;              //gap height

    public void drawPipe(Graphics g) {

        g.clearRect(0,0,750,500);                       //Clear screen
        g.drawRect(x1,y1,x2,y2);                        //Draw part 1
        g.drawRect(x1-3,y2-1,x2+6,25);                  //Draw part 2
        g.drawRect(x1-3,y2+25+gap,x2+6,25);             //Draw part 3
        g.drawRect(x1,y2+25+gap+25,x2,500-y2-49-gap);   //Draw part 4
    }

    public void move() {
        x1--;
    }

    public int getMyX() {   //To determine where the pipe is horizontally
        return x1-3;
    }

    public int getMyY() {   //To determine where the pipe is vertically
        return y2+25;
    }

    public int setHeightVal() {     //Get a random number and select a preset height
        int num = (int)(9*Math.random() + 1);
        int val = 0;
        if (num == 9)
        {
            val = 295;
        }
        else if (num == 8)
        {
            val = 246;
        }
        else if (num == 7)
        {
            val = 216;
        }
        else if (num == 6)
        {
            val = 185;
        }
        else if (num == 5)
        {
            val = 156;
        }
        else if (num == 4)
        {
            val = 125;
        }
        else if (num == 3)
        {
            val = 96;
        }
        else if (num == 2)
        {
            val = 66;
        }
        else
        {
            val = 25;
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the `CardLayout`.

Comment: Each and every inner class within a `.java` file is treated as a new `.class` when __javac__ executes to convert them into byte code. That is why `Main$1.class` for the first inner class that you see. You can use [java.beans.EventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html), that do not create classes randomly, though use them with care. For latter see [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349137/1057230) for [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: BTW - Happy 50+ rep.  Now you can leave comments on *any* question or answer.  :)

Comment: `Pipes` should be a `JPanel` class. And you want to use `PipeObject` objects not `Pipe` objects. You don't even have a `Pipe` class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to approach this is using a `CardLayout`.

[image]

[image]

### Notes

- A button with an `ActionListener` is far better than a `MouseListener` over a rectangle.

  - The button will show focus when the mouse is pointed at it, or the component is tabbed to via the keyboard.
  - The button is keyboard accessible.
  - The button has facility to support multiple icons built in (e.g. for 'initial look', focused, pressed etc.)
- White space in the GUI is provided around the menu panel and game by adding an `EmptyBorder`
- The button is made larger by setting a margin.
- Adjust margins, borders and preferred size according to need.  These sizes were set by me so as not to make the screenshots too large.
- See more tips in the code comments.

### Code

Here is the [MCTaRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example) that produced the above screenshots.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class PipesGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // the GUI as seen by the user (without frame)
                final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
                final JPanel gui = new JPanel(cl);
                // remove if no border is needed
                gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

                JPanel menu = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                JButton playGame = new JButton("Play!");
                ActionListener playGameListener = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        cl.show(gui, "game");
                    }
                };
                playGame.addActionListener(playGameListener);
                Insets margin = new Insets(20, 50, 20, 50);
                playGame.setMargin(margin);
                menu.add(playGame);
                gui.add(menu);
                cl.addLayoutComponent(menu, "menu");

                JPanel pipes = new Pipes();
                gui.add(pipes);
                cl.addLayoutComponent(pipes, "game");

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Pipes Game");
                f.add(gui);
                // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
                // all non-daemon threads are finished
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
                // in order display the components within it
                f.pack();
                // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
                // resizing artifacts.
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class Pipes extends JPanel {

    Pipes() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Pipes game appears here..", 170, 80);
    }

    @Override 
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // adjust to need
        return new Dimension(500,150);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will work on adding this. How do you take those nice screenshots?

Comment: *"How do you take those nice screenshots?"* See [How do I create a screenshot to illustrate a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post)?

Comment: Oh, I thought I'd remove the earlier comment, given your change of heart.  But reproduced the reply to your question.  ;)

Comment: Ha, so I'm trying to add this code, and I don't have the luxury of copy/paste. Grr...need wifi instead of LTE. Anyways, I have ONE error.  It says I need a semicolon after public void run().

Comment: Ohhh 100k nice...congrats

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well earned!

Comment: Added your code, but I was not able to load the pipes with it. The menu works perfectly though. Im adding a class to handle the pipes and changing the pipes class to be a single pipe object. Any suggestions? @AndrewThompson

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example) like I did (i.e. one source file, not 3 of them).

Answer (score 5):

> "Is there a way for me to add my GameMenu jpanel to my jframe, and then replace it with the Pipes jpanel?"

As other have suggested, for this you want a `CardLayout`. It is very simple to you.  Personally, I always wrap my `CardLayout` in a `JPanel` rather than the `JFrame`, just force of habit.

What you want to do is have a `mainPanel` that will have the `CardLayout`

```
CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
```

Then you want to add your panels to the `mainPanel`. What the `CardLyaout` does is *layer* the panels, making just *one* visible at a time. The first one you add, will the in the foreground. Also when you add the panel, you'll also want to issue it a *key* it can be called from. The key, can be any String you like.

```
mainPanel.add(gameMenu, "menu");
mainPnael.add(pipes, "pipe");
```

Now `gameMenu` is the only panel shown. To show `pipes`, all you do is use this method

- [`public void show(Container parent, String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show%28java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String%29) - Flips to the `parent` that was added to this layout with the specified `name`, using addLayoutComponent. If no such component exists, then nothing happens.

So you'd use, `card.show(mainPanel, "pipes");`

Whatever even you want to trigger the showing of `pipes`, just add that line in that event handler. You could add a button or something to the `GameMenu` that will allow movement to the `Pipes` panel.

Comment: @peeskillet  The barbie is warming up.  Where's that case of beer?  ;)  Cyber Storm: That is an in-joke about me reaching 100K rep.

Comment: @CyberStorm give it back to AndrewThompson. We need to get him his 100K. Either answer is a good answer :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I already drank it. You're taking too long to reach the milestone. I couldn't wait :P

Comment: @peeskillet  LOL!  In any case, the change of 'tick' has brought me back to 99.9 K.  Barbie is off..  :(

Comment: Both of you, take my +1.

Comment: @HugoSousa  You accepted that down-vote with such grace, that I have decided to remove it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson .. I too can spot bull excrement. We both know the 100k is misleading ;-D 37 to go!

Comment: @peeskillet  Too true!  I'm not entirely sure how you meant that, but given the number of down-votes I've made (thousands) and [bounties I've offered](http://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson?tab=bounties) (totaling 2150 rep.points) I figure I *could* have made 100K rep. a month ago.

Comment: @AndrewThompson 99,963 :)

Comment: @peeskillet  Yep.   Back to 100K.  I feel compelled to admit to you that I actually argued for the tick to come back to my answer.  If it is any consolation, know the following.  I will often open a question, see a reply by you, have a quick look over it, think *"That solves that!"*, add an up-vote and close the question.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson awww <sheds tear>

Answer (score 3):

This works with a mouse click on the menu. You can change it later, to a click on some button or whatever you want.

I added a `MouseListener` to the `Game` class. When the user presses the mouse on the `menu JPanel`, it adds the `Pipes JPanel` to `JFrame` and calls the `pack` method.

Game.java:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game {

    GameMenu menu = new GameMenu();
    Pipes game;
    boolean start = false;
    JFrame f;
    Rectangle2D menuRect = new Rectangle2D.Double(20, 20, 60, 40);

    public Game() {
        f = new JFrame();

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(menu);
        f.setTitle("Pipe Game");
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);



        menu.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                Point click = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                System.out.println("Clicked on the Panel");

                if(menuRect.contains(click))
                {
                    System.out.println("Clicked inside the Rectangle.");

                    start = true; 
                    menu.setVisible(false);
                    game = new Pipes();
                    f.add(game);
                    f.pack();

                    Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {  //pipe speed
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            game.move();
                        }
                    });
                    timer.start();

                    Timer refresh = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {    //refresh rate
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            game.repaint();
                        }
                    });
                    refresh.start();   
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Game();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to only trigger the event when the mouse is clicked inside the rectangle displayed in the GameMenu frame? For example, when the mouse is pressed, get the coordinates of the mouse and check if they are inside the rectangle?

Comment: You know the coordinates of the rectangle, so you can check it manually. There's also a `contains` method in `Rectangle2D`. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296438/adding-a-mouse-listener-to-a-rectangle-in-java

Comment: Updated my answer. It verifies if you click inside the Rectangle now.

Comment: Thanks Hugo, this will help

Comment: The -1 was for me @CyberStorm. Well, I accept this probably isn't the best approach to the problem, but at least it works. Wait for more answers, though.

Comment: Yea, I just noticed that. I'll keep an open mind to the solutions, but I can still use the listener. That part still solved one of my problems